# Ring adjunction equals quotient field

Tags: field-theory

What is the weakest requirement for a $z\in L/K$ so that $K[z]=K(z)$? Obviously if $z\in K$. And if $z$ is transcendent this equality never holds, right? What if $z$ is algebraic over $K$?

Comment: Yes. For $z$ algebraic, this holds (and it requires a proof !). In this case $K[z]$ itself is a field, $K[z]\simeq K[t]/(p(t))$, where $t$ is an indeterminate and $p(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $z$ over $K$.

Comment: I can see $K[z]\subset K(z)$. But the reverse inclusion is a problem still. I can imagine using a chain like $K(z)\subseteq K[z]\subseteq L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $L$ and $K$ are fields. Yes, you have precisely that the following are equivalent

1. $K[z] = K(z)$
2. $z$ is algebraic over $K$.

That (2) implies (1) is a standard argument, which I can repeat if needed.

To show that (1) implies (2), this is trivial if $z = 0$, If $z \ne 0$, and thus $z$ is invertibile, we will have
$$
z^{-1} \in K(z) = K[z],
$$
and thus there is a polynomial $a_{0} + a_{1} x + \dots + a_{n} x^{n} \in K[x]$ such that
$$
z^{-1} = a_{0} + a_{1} z + \dots + a_{n} z^{n}.
$$
Multiplying by $z$ on both sides we get
$$
-1 + a_{0} z + a_{1} z^{2} + \dots + a_{n} z^{n+1} = 0,
$$
so that $z$ is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: And we obtain the other implication by using $a_n z^n+\dots+a_0=0$ so we have $-(\frac{a_n}{a_0}z^{n-1}+\dots+\frac{a_1}{a_0})z=1$ for $z\neq 0$ (so $a_0\neq 0$).

Comment: @J.V thanks for accepting my answer. I think the other implication is slightly more complicated, because with your argument you are only proving that $z^{-1} \in K[z]$, whereas it is not clear for instance why $(z - 1)^{-1} \in K[z]$ (for $z \ne 1$). For the other implication I think one should go through the fact that the minimal polynomial of $z$ over $K$ is irreducible.

Comment: Can't I just say that every Element of $K[z]$ is algebraic and therefore we can construct its inverse exactly as I did above?

Comment: @J.V yes indeed. Sorry for taking so long to reply, it's a busy time here.